# Js conditional display on click

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements, addeventlistener

I'm doing an online portfolio project where in the "about me" section I want to have 3 different tabs: life, education, experience.
At first page load, the first one will be visible, and after clicking another, that one's text will appear instead of the previous one.

```
let about_me_data = [
    {
        "title": "Life",
        "text": "Nullam ac quam non risus dictum viverra non id massa. Donec rhoncus sem at leo iaculis, tempor facilisis sem porttitor. Praesent sit amet quam ultricies, vulputate odio hendrerit, dictum eros. Aenean mattis ultricies tempus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam imperdiet dolor et dignissim luctus. Morbi laoreet tempor feugiat."
    },
    {
        "title": "Education",
        "text": "Sed malesuada porta quam. Proin pretium eu augue vitae pellentesque. Nullam volutpat urna ac tellus bibendum tincidunt. Maecenas ultrices et nunc consectetur cursus. Suspendisse varius vitae risus sed aliquam. Cras nisi leo, scelerisque at dolor sed, sagittis eleifend nisl. Etiam id arcu luctus, vehicula arcu id, dictum nisi. Nullam aliquet ultricies erat. Vivamus a ultrices velit, ac malesuada elit."
    },
    { 
        "title": "Experience",
        "text": "Integer non maximus arcu. Nullam ut odio quis ligula interdum consectetur. Aliquam dignissim eu nibh ut accumsan. Phasellus volutpat nibh lorem, ac efficitur justo cursus ut. Etiam sed rutrum elit. Aenean lacus velit, sollicitudin quis malesuada nec, vestibulum eu tortor. Aenean dapibus commodo nibh ac ornare."
    }
];

for (i = 0; i < about_me_data.length; i++){
    let title = document.createElement('p');
    title.innerHTML = about_me_data[i].title;
    title.setAttribute('class', 'about-me-tabs hvr-underline-from-center');
    title.addEventListener('click', conditionalDisplay(i));
    document.getElementById('about-me-tabs-titles').appendChild(title);
};

function displayFirstTab(){
    let firstTab = document.createElement('p');
    firstTab.innerHTML = about_me_data[0].text;
    document.getElementById('about-me-tabs-text').appendChild(firstTab);
};
window.onload(displayFirstTab());

function conditionalDisplay(i) {
    let text = document.createElement('p');
    text.innerHTML = about_me_data[i].text;
    document.getElementById('about-me-tabs-text').appendChild(text);
};
```

This is what I've tried to do.
I just don't know where should I write the conditionalDisplay function or what I should pass to it - "i" or the title clicked.

Another way I've tried is this (still not working):

```
for (i = 0; i < about_me_data.length; i++){
    title.addEventListener('click', conditionalDisplay(title.innerHTML));
};

function conditionalDisplay(title) {
    let text = document.createElement('p');
 
    if (title === about_me_data[0].title) {
        text.innerHTML = about_me_data[0].text;
        document.getElementById('about-me-tabs-text').appendChild(text);
    } else if (title === about_me_data[1].title) {
        text.innerHTML = about_me_data[1].text;
        document.getElementById('about-me-tabs-text').appendChild(text);
    } else if (title === about_me_data[2].title) {
        text.innerHTML = about_me_data[2].text;
        document.getElementById('about-me-tabs-text').appendChild(text);
    };
};
```

```
<div id="about-me-tabs-titles"></div>
<div id="about-me-tabs-text"></div>
```

This is where I'm trying to display my texts.

Using the above try, all 3 texts are displayed + the one from displayFirstTab func.
I need a way to be able to apply hidden/visible style to them, one at a time and remove it from the previous one when clicking another.

I've done this by writing it all step by step but I would like a more automated function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML

Comment: Added at the end. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your codebase there are some errors:

- `window.onload` should be a function that will be called when page and related stuff are already loaded. You're trying to call `displayFirstTab` immediately without waiting for markup load event;
- Commonly, every code which interacts with a markup on the page should be used only when such markup is ready. That's why I moved code which creates titles inside `window.onload`;
- Because you're having only one text for the selected title at a time then it's no sense to use `appendChild`. That's why I change it to modifying `innerText` property of the element;
- You have a misunderstanding of how `addEventListener` works. You need to pass a function as an argument to `addEventListener`, and that function will be called when such an event will be triggered;

Here is the corrected:

```
    let about_me_data = [
        {
            "title": "Life",
            "text": "Nullam ac quam non risus dictum viverra non id massa. Donec rhoncus sem at leo iaculis, tempor facilisis sem porttitor. Praesent sit amet quam ultricies, vulputate odio hendrerit, dictum eros. Aenean mattis ultricies tempus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam imperdiet dolor et dignissim luctus. Morbi laoreet tempor feugiat."
        },
        {
            "title": "Education",
            "text": "Sed malesuada porta quam. Proin pretium eu augue vitae pellentesque. Nullam volutpat urna ac tellus bibendum tincidunt. Maecenas ultrices et nunc consectetur cursus. Suspendisse varius vitae risus sed aliquam. Cras nisi leo, scelerisque at dolor sed, sagittis eleifend nisl. Etiam id arcu luctus, vehicula arcu id, dictum nisi. Nullam aliquet ultricies erat. Vivamus a ultrices velit, ac malesuada elit."
        },
        {
            "title": "Experience",
            "text": "Integer non maximus arcu. Nullam ut odio quis ligula interdum consectetur. Aliquam dignissim eu nibh ut accumsan. Phasellus volutpat nibh lorem, ac efficitur justo cursus ut. Etiam sed rutrum elit. Aenean lacus velit, sollicitudin quis malesuada nec, vestibulum eu tortor. Aenean dapibus commodo nibh ac ornare."
        }
    ];

    function displayFirstTab(){
        document.getElementById('about-me-tabs-text').innerText = about_me_data[0].text;
    }

    function conditionalDisplay(i) {
        return function() {
            document.getElementById('about-me-tabs-text').innerText = about_me_data[i].text;
        }
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        displayFirstTab();

        for (i = 0; i < about_me_data.length; i++) {
            let title = document.createElement('p');
            title.innerHTML = about_me_data[i].title;
            title.setAttribute('class', 'about-me-tabs hvr-underline-from-center');
            title.addEventListener('click', conditionalDisplay(i));
            document.getElementById('about-me-tabs-titles').appendChild(title);
        }
    };
```

For this markup:

```
<div id="about-me-tabs-titles"></div>
<p id="about-me-tabs-text"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the title as class of the elements like the following way:

```js
let about_me_data = [
    {
        "title": "Life",
        "text": "Nullam ac quam non risus dictum viverra non id massa. Donec rhoncus sem at leo iaculis, tempor facilisis sem porttitor. Praesent sit amet quam ultricies, vulputate odio hendrerit, dictum eros. Aenean mattis ultricies tempus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam imperdiet dolor et dignissim luctus. Morbi laoreet tempor feugiat."
    },
    {
        "title": "Education",
        "text": "Sed malesuada porta quam. Proin pretium eu augue vitae pellentesque. Nullam volutpat urna ac tellus bibendum tincidunt. Maecenas ultrices et nunc consectetur cursus. Suspendisse varius vitae risus sed aliquam. Cras nisi leo, scelerisque at dolor sed, sagittis eleifend nisl. Etiam id arcu luctus, vehicula arcu id, dictum nisi. Nullam aliquet ultricies erat. Vivamus a ultrices velit, ac malesuada elit."
    },
    { 
        "title": "Experience",
        "text": "Integer non maximus arcu. Nullam ut odio quis ligula interdum consectetur. Aliquam dignissim eu nibh ut accumsan. Phasellus volutpat nibh lorem, ac efficitur justo cursus ut. Etiam sed rutrum elit. Aenean lacus velit, sollicitudin quis malesuada nec, vestibulum eu tortor. Aenean dapibus commodo nibh ac ornare."
    }
];

for (let i = 0; i < about_me_data.length; i++){
  let title = document.createElement('p');
  title.innerHTML = about_me_data[i].title;
  title.setAttribute('class', 'about-me-tabs hvr-underline-from-center');
  //wrap the function call with anonymous function so that it can be called only when clicked
  title.addEventListener('click', function(){ conditionalDisplay(i, about_me_data[i].title)});
  document.getElementById('about-me-tabs-titles').appendChild(title);
  conditionalDisplay(i, about_me_data[i].title);
};

function displayFirstTab(){
  //get all p
  var all = document.querySelectorAll('#about-me-tabs-text p');
  //show first and hide rest
  all.forEach((i,idx) => idx==0? i.style.display="block":i.style.display="none");
};


function conditionalDisplay(i, cls) {
  //get all
  var all = document.querySelectorAll('#about-me-tabs-text p');
  //hide all
  all.forEach(i => i.style.display="none");
  //get the current element by maching the class
  var current = document.querySelector(`.${cls}`);
  if(current != null){
    //show the current element
    current.style.display="block"
  }
  else{
    //create element if not exist
    let text = document.createElement('p');
    text.innerHTML = about_me_data[i].text;
    text.classList.add(cls);
    document.getElementById('about-me-tabs-text').appendChild(text);
  }
};

displayFirstTab();
```

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-row" id="about-me-tabs-titles"></div>
<div id="about-me-tabs-text"></div>
```